# Use filter function to extract list from incontiguous cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365, excel-filter

I am attempting to make a form create a list (purple) of all the subtotals (blue).

Within this list I do not want to include subtotals which have a value of 0.

[image: Overview of form]

Given this, the form with the current subtotals should look like this:

[image: Correct subtotals]

I have spent a long time trying to figure out how to do this, there are formulas on the internet such as:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$26,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$26=$K$1,ROW($A$2:$A$26)),ROW(1:1))-1,1),””)}
```

These formulas do not work as they require a contiguous cell range to form an array which I do not have due to the formatting of my sheet.

Even if I compromised and provided a contiguous cell range by omitting the bottom two blue cells, the above formula must be adapted to exclude both 0 values, and values of "" / blank cells; something I was not able to do.

With more looking I have come up with my own formula which I feel is very close to working but not quite:

```
{=IFERROR(FILTER(TRANSPOSE(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13}, I24,I26,I30,I31,I32,I33,I37,I38,I44,I47,I50,I54,I55)), TRANSPOSE(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13}, I24,I26,I30,I31,I32,I33,I37,I38,I44,I47,I50,I54,I55))<>0), "")}
```

To me it reads, choose the first thirteen values of the blue cells I24, I26 etc (There are only 13 blue/green cells) and display them as a horizontal array.
Convert to vertical array.
Filter the above array to only allow values not equal to 0.
If an error occurs, display nothing.

This populates a list like this:

[image: populated list with n/a errors]

**1. I don't understand why N/A is displayed when I have used the iferror function.**

Finally, when there is only one subtotal to display, it looks like this:

[image: Populated list with repeating value error]

**2. I don't understand why the value repeats like this.**

Thanks for any help

Comment: Edited, thanks for that.

Comment: have you tried `FILTER(I24:I55,(I24:I55<>"")*(I24:I55<>0))`? That should work. Also in Excel 365 you don't need to select the whole input range, just insert your formula into A7.

Comment: Thank you for your time, much much neater than my equation, but this still gives an error in empty cells in the list, even when I add the iferror function to your equation.

Comment: There should not be any error. You should enter this formula only to one cell, not into the whole range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula in cell A7:

```
=FILTER(I24:I55,(I24:I55<>0)*(H24:H55<>"Subtotal"))
```

So, we are filtering column I for non-zero amounts on those rows where column H is not "Subtotal".

Comment: As above this looks like a really nice solution, but this still gives an error in empty cells in the list, for some reason.

Comment: Please edit your post, showing exactly where you have entered this formula and where the errors are, also what error is shown. To confirm, you should enter this formula in the first row only and there must be no cells with data in the range under the row you have entered the formula in.

Comment: Apologies, it works perfectly bar a iferror function. My issue was that I was entering it (into the first cell only) with ctrl+shift+enter as I thought it was an array formula. However it only needs enter to work. Thank you so much